# Can't get Google Now card to trigger from email

Tags: html, email, schema.org, google-now, json-ld

I've followed the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/google-now-cards 
and I cannot get an event card to show up in my google now.  I have noticed that some of the test emails I sent yesterday using this link http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/ (as suggested by the tutorial) have correctly showed the "Modify Reservation" button in Gmail but it seems like this doesn't show up immediately.  I'm wondering if Google is doing some processing on the backend that takes some time to propagate into my inbox.  I'm also wondering if Google Now Cards will only work if you schedule something at least one day in the future.

Has anyone gotten this to work?   If so, was there any "gotchas" that aren't obvious from the Google Tutorial?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got this to work.  For some reason the starter tutorial they provide doesn't give you adequate markup to generate a google now card.  Instead, you should use the event without reservation markup [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation).